# What library can I use to configure most or all GigE and/or Camera Link cameras?

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, opencv

GenICam seemed like the best alternative, however the documentation is sparse.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not cheap - but the only lib I can think of that transparently supports Gig-E and Cameralink is [Matrox Imaging Library MIL](http://www.matrox.com/imaging/en/products/software/).

It's also the platform that most camera link camera markers support with config files

Comment: Found a handful of libraries, most of them are wrappers for the GenApi, but yours looks good too. I was looking for pricing, and couldn't find it, do you know where I could pricing information for that particular piece of software?

Comment: @Louis93 call Matrox, it's one of those "if you have to ask the price...." and they wrap it with a bunch of support contracts and run time licenses. Typically $2-3K for a development seat and a few $100 runtime if you don't use their boards

Comment: many vendor libraries are doing this now and cover whatever technologies they do.  Many are substantially cheaper than MIL too.  This had more weight at the time of writing but at the current time I think this  should be downvoted so people are aware lots of vendors are addressing this problem.  There's nothing FOSS for this problem though.

Comment: @JasonNewton is there much support for CameraLink anymore? There are ac ouple more questions on GigE/USB3 vision I answered. If I get some free time I will look at adding USB3 vision to Opencv ( I don't have any Gig-E hw)

Comment: @MartinBeckett yep - it depends on where you look but many vendors can't ignore it since it's pretty darn simple and military applications also seem to like it alot.  Example SDKs would be Basler's Pylon and Teledyne Dalsa's Sapera.  Seems to be a function of whether or not that company still produces camera link cameras + GigE or supports GenTL.   The GenTL effort brings GenICam support to CameraLink (I don't know vendor libraries for this but I never looked).  JAI has this as a result: http://www.jai.com/en/support/jai_sdk_and_control_tool provided you have GenTL drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Most libraries are built on GenICam's reference implementation - freely downloadable from their site.  If you just wish to configure a camera, Pleora has a viewer which will let you visit nearly any node/setting declared on the camera.  Their SDK license is much cheaper than Matrox's too if you want to do image acquisition or configure the camera from a program.